# youtube api v3 comments to videos for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, youtube-api

I am developing an app on iPhone which view my channel only and I need to make a comments on the videos. I've used youtube-api v2.0 and it always respond with an error.
And I've googled along for a comments API in V3.0 but with no results.
Do anyone can review the following code, I may implemented something wrong, else Please tell me how to develop it.

```
    -(IBAction)commentClicked:(id)sender{
    NSString *urlStr=@"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/mobile/videos/W_KEuea8eIw/comments";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    NSString *xmlString = @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><entry xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom\"xmlns:yt=\"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007;\"><content>This is a crazy video</content></entry/>";
        [ request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
        [request setValue:@"application/atom+xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
         [request setHTTPBody:[xmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setValue:@"2.1" forHTTPHeaderField:@"GData-Version"];
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%@",kSampleDeveloperKey] forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-GData-Key"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@",self.auth.accessToken] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *err;
    NSData*returnData=[ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];
    NSLog(@"responseData: %@", content);
}
```

here is the responsedata

```
 <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
    <error>
<domain>GData</domain>
<code>ParseException</code>
<internalReason>Element type "entry" must be followed by either attribute specifications, "&gt;" or "/&gt;".</internalReason>
</error>
</errors>
```

Comment: There is no support for comments in v3 of the API, and we don't have any information as to if/when they will be added. You should be able to use v2, but you're not providing us with enough information to tell you why it isn't working. Please edit your question to include the error in the HTTP response body that you get back.

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Posnick : I have edited the response as shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of your XML string reads `</entry/>`, which is not a valid closing tag. You want `</entry>`.